# Django SQLite3 db doesn't recognise math function when called through raw query

Tags: database, django, sqlite

I am pretty sure I just missed some stupid little thing , but yet it keeps me from going further.  I get this error

> "DatabaseError at / no such function: SQRT" ,

and I get such error on every math function like mod  etc... So I am a little confused. Does sqlite3 have no math functions , which I guess is a little absurd , or is it me just being stupid O_O

```
def check_difference(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()   
    cursor.execute("SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t1.id) AS rep, MAX(t3.right_key) AS max_right \
                    FROM cms_Book AS t1, cms_Book AS t2, cms_Book AS t3\
                    WHERE t1.left_key <> t2.left_key \
                    AND t1.left_key <> t2.right_key \
                    AND t1.right_key <> t2.left_key \
                    AND t1.right_key <> t2.right_key \
                    GROUP BY t1.id \
                    HAVING max_right <> SQRT(4 * rep + 1) + 1 ")
    q = cursor.fetchall()
    return q
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQRT` is available in sqlite3 through an extension:

- http://www.sqlite.org/contrib/, see `extension-functions.c`

> This library will provide common mathematical and string functions in
>   SQL queries using the operating system libraries or provided
>   definitions.  It includes the following functions:
>
> Math: acos, asin, atan, atn2, atan2, acosh, asinh, atanh, difference,
>   degrees, radians, cos, sin, tan, cot, cosh, sinh, tanh, coth, exp,
>   log, log10, power, sign, **sqrt**, square, ceil, floor, pi.

Note that the extension loading mechanism may be off by default (for security reasons - see ticket [#1863](http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?c=2006-06-27+15%3A16%3A15)) - so you'll need to recompile sqlite3 from source. In the *autoconf* distribution, extension loading is enabled by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpful . At least now i now for sure that extension library is needed. Dont now i missed it.  But just faced another problem . Can't find how to add .c extension to django . Perhaps you could point to some resources where it is described?

Comment: Take a look at this function, which exposes library loading to SQL: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension

Comment: Ehhhh.. i am sorry for being stupid and asking stupid questions. But after searching the internet i could not find how to import extension file to sqlite3 embed in Django with load_extension() , because i don't understand which file must contain this line , and my wild guess is you need to download and install sqlite3 (pretty sure i am talking nonsense). So i thought whatever :D i wanted to install mysql database anyway . But after some time i ran on another problem.Is there mysqldb for python 2.7.1 , because i was unable to find?The only thing Sourceforge gave me was "MySQL versions 3.23-5.1"

Comment: and Python versions 2.3-2.6 " and Google apparently too , which of course shows me error when i try to install it . So any further help for idiots like is appreciated ~~. I am embarassed.

Comment: @Viktor: The MySQL versions (3.23-5.1) you see are not related to the python version. Just pick the most recent MySQL, then install [mysql-python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/).

Comment: Then why do i get this error? What file can't he find ?               F:\Users\Cha0s\Desktop\MySQL-python-1.2.3>python setup.py install 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()   
  File "F:\Users\Cha0s\Desktop\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key']) 
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind . Downloaded MySQLdb from here http://www.codegood.com/archives/129 , installed and so far works fine. >.< Not really sure why it gave error before. Maybe sometghing was wrong with registry or maybe downloaded 32 bit for 64 bit python . =)